# Winui 3 winrt C++ reference counting

Tags: c++, memory, append, windows-runtime, winui-3

Using WinUI 3, Winrt C++ in the following code: 
Is myRectangle reference counted? Or is it copied?

```
namespace winrt::MyProject::implementation{

void MyProjectClass::fnc(){

winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Canvas myCanvas = CanvasElementFromXAML();
winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Rectangle myRectangle;
myCanvas.Children.Append(myRectangle);

}
}
```

I see this type of code in examples. In C++ (without MS extensions) this would lead to a dangling reference/pointer if not copied, since myRectangle is a local var which will go out of scope.
myCanvas.Children.Append() receives UIElement const& value 
[void Append(UIElement const& value)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.append?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-uielementcollection-append(windows-ui-xaml-uielement))

here the const reference would communicate that the argument cannot be changed, therefore ref count cannot be modified.

Comment: The upside of winrt C++ is that you typically don't have to think about reference counting, dangling pointers, and stuff going out of scope.  That is, your code is fine as you have it.

The downside of winrt is that the moment you have doubts about the upside, you'll easily confuse yourself even more. I've been there myself.

Comment: Most of the time, think of winrt instances as "smart pointers" that carry the reference count across assignments and function calls. A COM/cppwinrt expert might be able to articulate this better than I can.

Comment: WinRT is COM-based, so the Canvas instance and the Rectangle instance are both COM-objects. Append implementation will call AddRef on myRectangle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-addref in this case, there's no specific MS extension involved.

Comment: @SimonMourier pls add your comment as an answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT is [COM-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021694/what-is-c-winrt-exactly), so the `Canvas` instance and the `Rectangle` instance are both COM-objects.

So, `Append` implementation will call [AddRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-addref) on `myRectangle`. In this case, there's no specific MS extension involved.