# C++ language projection

Tags: c++, windows, c++-winrt

Can you explain in your own words what it means: Standard C++17 language projection for Windows Runtime API (WinRT) (examples are welcome)?

On the microsovt website, everything is so complicatedly described that I could not understand this term

Comment: Referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/. It's an odd term, and in a quick skim I don't know what it's supposed to mean. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/WinRT

Comment: Agree it's an awkward term, but I believe they're just referring to making a wrapper which maps COM features (interfaces, threads, sinks) to a C++17 syntax that feels natural. Contrast that with other MS COM wrappers like `_com_ptr_t<>` which, while convenient back in the 90's, feel clunky by C++17 standards.

Comment: You may want to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021694/what-is-c-winrt-exactly/60045394#60045394).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This confusion goes all the way back to Microsoft's monumental communication disaster in explaining **what** the Windows Runtime is. In broad terms, it is [the foundational technology that underpins the "future" of the Windows API](https://web.archive.org/web/20221128050413/https://kennykerr.ca/2014/09/02/the-essentials-of-the-windows-runtime/) (that "future" had arrived well over a decade ago).

The Windows Runtime<sup>1</sup> is based on an evolution of [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model), inheriting one of its fundamental properties: A strict [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) contract, enabling language-agnosticism. Either side of the ABI can be written in just about any programming language.

Functionality in the Windows Runtime is deployed by way of [Windows Runtime Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/). WinRT components generally consist of two parts:

- A [WinMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winmd-files) file that describes the provided interfaces in a machine-readable way
- A binary that implements the functionality

While possible to communicate with WinRT components right at the ABI (using either the [WRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl), or straight C) this can quickly become unwieldy and error prone. This is where "language projections" come into play: Generally tool- and library-based, they "project" the raw ABI into more manageable, safer abstractions for a given programming language (e.g. [C++](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt), [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT), or [Rust](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/)).

The C++/WinRT language projection provides a large array of translations, including

- Automatic reference counting, courtesy of the [`com_ptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr) class template
- Translation between C++ exceptions and ABI-compatible `HRESULT` error codes
- Exposing asynchronous operations as C++20 coroutines
- Mapping [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#delegates) to anything that provides a function call operator (such as functions, member functions, lambda expressions, etc.)
- Seamless translations between WinRT date and time primitives and [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) types
- Exposing [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#static-and-instance-methods) instance methods as `static` class members (even though they are technically implemented on the type's [activation factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/activation/nn-activation-iactivationfactory))
- ...

In short, a language projection makes WinRT types appear as natural as possible for any given language, hiding all aspects of the ABI, with the intention of making the Windows Runtime accessible to programmers that don't (care to) know about the technology's internals.

To this day, that plan only really panned out for C# developers (which, ironically, predominantly assume that the Windows Runtime were powered by the [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)).

---

<sup>1</sup> *A misnomer, sorry. It doesn't contain any sort of runtime component in the traditional sense.*